# Easiest way to increment a field in the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there an easier way to increment a field in my database with Rails, than doing this:

```
@user.update_attribute(:last_seen_at, @user.last_seen_at+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`increment`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment):

> Initializes `attribute` to zero if `nil` and adds the value passed as `by` (default is 1). The increment is performed directly on the underlying attribute, no setter is invoked. Only makes sense for number-based attributes. Returns `self`.

Example:

```
@user.increment(:last_seen_at)
```

Comment: This works as well, but turns out it will need `@user.save` also to save the increment

Comment: `increment!` saves the record.

Comment: `increment!` worked! Thanks -- much more "ruby like" solution

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You can pretend it's a counter cache and use:

```
User.increment_counter(:last_seen_at, @user.id)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/increment_counter

**Edit:** I should mention that this won't work if you are relying on the behavior of dates or times (i.e. `Date.today + 1`). In that case, I think your best bet is to just do the `update_attribute` thing.